# Line graphs called "graph derivatives": any intuition?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, terminology, differential-operators, laplacian

***Short version:** in several papers, [line graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph) (and closely related graphs) are called *graph derivatives* or *derived graphs*; is there any intuition for such terminologies, in connection with the classical concept of derivative?*

---

***Full version of the question.***

In a 1961 paper entitled *[Graph Derivatives](https://eudml.org/doc/169965)*, Gert Sabidussi defines the *graph derivative $\delta G$* of a graph $G$; it is nothing but the nowadays classical [line graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph) of $G$.

Similarly, in 1970, Lowell W. Beineke calls this graph the *derived graph* of $G$ in his paper entitled *[Characterizations of derived graphs](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0021-9800(70)80019-9)*.

In 2017, a PhD dissertation entitled [*Structures of Derived Graphs*](https://scholarworks.wmich.edu/dissertations/3204/) was awarded to Khawlah Hamad Alhulwah at Western Michigan University. A large part of this work is about line graphs, and it gives the following intuition: "a *derived graph* of G is a graph obtained from G by a graph operation of some type."

It however seems to me that Sabidussi and Beineke (and, probably, others) had in mind a deeper connection between line graphs and the classical concept of (function) derivative.

In another line of works, the *derived graph* of $G$ has the same vertices as $G$ but they are connected by an edge if the distance between them in $G$ is $2$. This terminology was introduced in the 2009 paper *[Bounds On The Second Stage Spectral Radius Of Graphs](https://zenodo.org/record/1071578)* by Ayyaswamy, Balachandran and Kannan, and further studied for instance in the 2012 paper *[Derived graphs of some graphs](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268015448_Derived_graphs_of_some_graphs)* by Jog, Hande, Gutman, and Bozkurt. However, I can't find any explanation for this terminology in these papers.

> My questions are:
>
> - is there any reason to call line graphs *graph derivatives*? are they related to some extension of classical derivatives in a way that I miss?
> - are there other definitions of *graph derivatives* that may be seen as such extensions?

Comment: And what about the Cantor-Bendixson derivative of a point set? In the same vein, are there deep connections between perfect numbers, perfect sets, and perfect graphs.?

Comment: And what about the derived subgroup of a group?

Comment: Do you suggest that there is no connection at all? It seems to me that the mentioned authors had a connection in mind, but really this is my question (and I would be happy to learn there is no connection, as happy as with the converse).

Comment: I don't know. I'll be as interested to get an authoritative answer as you are. I suspect that when $A$ is a derived $B$, it just means you get $A$ from $B$ by some well-defined procedure, but I'd like to hear from someone who actually knows.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That is what I suspect, too. But the fact that some authors call them _derivatives_ (not just _derived_) and denote them by $\delta G$ makes me unsure.

Comment: I posted a related question here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/392391/differentiation-of-functions-over-graphs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just found the answer to this question in the paper *[Synthesis and analysis in total variation regularization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.06418)* by Francesco Ortelli and Sara van de Geer.

In the abstract, they write "*We give a definition of the discrete graph derivative operator based on the notion of line graph*", and they do so in Section 1.2. They use (a directed version of) the [incidence matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix#Graph_theory) of a (directed) graph, and notice it may be used to differentiate a signal on the vertices of the graph along its edges, like [gmvh](https://mathoverflow.net/users/45250/gmvh) suggests in [the answer above](https://mathoverflow.net/q/389970). Then, in order to iterate such derivations, they introduce the (directed) line graph and say:

> The idea behind using the line graph is the following: when computing
> differences along the direction of the graph, we obtain a value for
> each edge of the graph. Since we follow the direction of the edges,
> these values represent the first discrete derivative of the signal
> with respect to the graph, and constitute the vertices of the line
> graph.

They finally define the *k-th order discrete graph derivative operator* from the incidence matrix of iterated line graphs (meaning that they take the line graph of the line graph of the line graph etc).

**It turns out that yes, line graphs and derivatives are strongly related!**

Answer (score 12):

If one considers a graph $G=(V,E)$ and a function $f:V\to\mathbb{R}$, it makes sense to look at the finite differences $f(v_i)-f(v_j)$ for neighboring vertices $v_i,v_j\in V$ as a sort of discrete derivative of $f$ (strictly speaking, this makes sense only for a directed graph, otherwise the sign isn't defined). If the graph is a discrete approximation (e.g. a triangulation or some sort of lattice) of some manifold, then this can be seen as a discretization of $\partial f$ (after weighting by edge length). The line graph is then the graph on whose vertices these discrete derivatives live, so it makes sense to see it as a sort of derivative of $G$ itself.

Comment: Nice, thank you! Equivalently, one may say that $\delta f$ lives on $G$ edges, right? Is there some benefit to seeing it as living on its line graph vertices? May it make further operations easier, like iterating the _derivation_?

Comment: Yeah, I'd say it makes iterating easier.

Comment: I just found a paper explaining just this, and using it precisely for iteration purposes, with the use of incidence matrices. See the details in the answer I posted below (too long for a comment). Thank you for your help!