# Reference request for differential graph theory

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

*Disclaimer*: This question [was initially](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4718589) asked yesterday in Mathematics Stack Exchange but left unanswered there.

---

I am interested in learning about differential graph theory or differential operators on graphs, something related to what [E. Bautista](https://mathoverflow.net/users/173461/e-bautista) introduced in his answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/392391/differentiation-of-functions-over-graphs). Can one suggest a textbook in which such topics are discussed? (The quoted answer refers to some papers, but I prefer a book covering a comprehensive treatment of the topic.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's a recent monograph on different flavours of graph Laplacians by Kostenko and Nicolussi: [https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~kostenko/list/GraphLaplInf.pdf](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Ekostenko/list/GraphLaplInf.pdf)

But I'd say that the topic is too vast to be sufficiently covered in any single coherent book; you have such different appearances of operators related to edgewise derivative! To list just a few:

- random walks on finitely generated groups (there are thousands of papers on this!)
- expander graphs, and other isoperimetric properties related to amenability (Cheeger constants, cost of a group)
- geodesic flow on hyperbolic groups
- spectral theory of random graphs
- Selberg-like trace formulas
- Gromov's proof of Stallings splitting theorem via harmonic functions
- *...here someone more knowledgeable may insert ten times more topics, because I do not know much of it outside of applications to group theory; I would be interested myself to see an operator which is* not *a variant of Laplacian used to do something meaningful*.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to look at the book listed below. I guess you can find it on the internet.

**P. M. Soardi,**
*Potential theory on infinite networks.*
Lecture Notes in Math., 1590
Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1994.